# How to Insert Values Based On One Existing Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to fill out based on the values in another column. Please see my script below and let me know how I can avoid the last line overwriting the previous statements. Thank you so much for your help in advance!

```
data_xls['New'] = np.where(data_xls['Old'].str.contains('(?:ps1)', regex=True), "Promoted Story", "" )
data_xls['New'] = np.where(data_xls['Old'].str.contains('(?:native)', regex=True), "Native","" )
data_xls['New'] = np.where(data_xls['Old'].str.contains('(?:email)', regex=True), "Email", "" )
data_xls['New'] = np.where(data_xls['Old'].str.contains('(?:email)', regex=True), "InMail","" )
data_xls['New'] = np.where(data_xls['Old'].str.contains('(?:sponsored)', regex=True), "Sponsored Content","")
```

Thank you,
Tae

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal set of input data, and matching desired output?

Comment: This may help you. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html